# How to show every layer in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a very easy model in keras. I defined a function to get vgg19 network and then connect it with a flatten layer and then a dense layer. When I print the model summary, it does not show every layer in the vgg19 network. Is there any way to show that without changing the function about vgg19? Any advice is appreciated.

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten
from keras.models import Model


input = Input(shape=(32,32,3), name="main_input")

def Model_vgg19(input_shape,input):
    vgg19_model = keras.applications.VGG19(
        input_shape=(32,32,3),
        weights='imagenet',
        include_top=False
    )(input)
    return vgg19_model

model = Model_vgg19((32,32,3),input)
model = Flatten()(model)
model = Dense(10, activation='relu', name='features_inc')(model)

model = Model(input, model)
model.summary()
```

The result is like

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
main_input (InputLayer)      (None, 32, 32, 3)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
vgg19 (Model)                (None, 1, 1, 512)         20024384  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
features_inc (Dense)         (None, 10)                5130      
=================================================================
Total params: 20,029,514
Trainable params: 20,029,514
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: with model.layers[1].summary() you can print the vgg summary

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method get_layer(name, index) on your model type. you can find more information about it here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#get_layer

for your code, you can use this:

```
model.get_layer(index=1).summary()
```

With this, you will get the summary of the VGG19 model (which is index 1 at your model). Good luck!

Comment: You can also use the layer name, `model.get_layer('vgg19').summary()`

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
vgg19_model = keras.applications.VGG19(
        input_shape=(32,32,3),
        weights='imagenet',
        include_top=False
    )
x=vgg19_model.output
x=Flatten()(x)
# use `output =` instead `output == `
output = Dense(10, activation='relu', name='features_inc')(x)
model=Model(inputs=vgg19_model.input, outputs=output)
```

Just a side note. The VGG model has a parameter pooling. If you set pooling='max' the output layer is a max pooling layer that you can feed directly into a dense layer so you do not need to include the flatten layer.